# How to resolve Error: Cycle in Terraform when working with IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a aws_scheduler_schedule that is scheduled to send a message every minute to a Lambda Function, as shown below:

```
resource "aws_scheduler_schedule" "event_scheduler" {
  name       = "${var.environment}-${var.account_name}-${var.service_name}-scheduler"

  flexible_time_window {
    mode = "OFF"
  }

  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"

  target {
    arn      = var.lambda_arn
    role_arn = aws_iam_role.iam_for_eventbridge.arn

    input = jsonencode({
      MessageBody = "check_expired"
    })
  }
}
```

I want to limit the aws_iam_role for the aws_scheduler_schedule, such that it only allows the above scheduler to sts:AssumeRole. This is my code for the aws_iam_role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_eventbridge" {
  name                = "${var.environment}-${var.account_name}-${var.service_name}-eventbridge-role"
  assume_role_policy  = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "scheduler.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
              "ArnEquals": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "${aws_scheduler_schedule.event_scheduler.arn}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: Cycle: aws_scheduler_schedule.event_scheduler, aws_iam_role.iam_for_eventbridge

I understand that this is because the role requires the scheduler and the scheduler requires the role. How do I achieve the restriction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem that can be solved by creating a variable for the IAM role name:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

locals {
  role_name = "${var.environment}-${var.account_name}-${var.service_name}-eventbridge-role"
  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${local.role_name}"
}

resource "aws_scheduler_schedule" "event_scheduler" {
  name       = "${var.environment}-${var.account_name}-${var.service_name}-scheduler"

  flexible_time_window {
    mode = "OFF"
  }

  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"

  target {
    arn      = var.lambda_arn
    role_arn = local.role_arn

    input = jsonencode({
      MessageBody = "check_expired"
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_eventbridge" {
  name                = local.role_name
  assume_role_policy  = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "scheduler.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
              "ArnEquals": {
                "iam:AssociatedResourceARN": [
                    "${aws_scheduler_schedule.event_scheduler.arn}"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```